# How to use multiple background colors for header and bottom?

Tags: css

How can I use multiple colors for my website?

I am using `gradient` colors for the header, it looks like ![this][1] I want to also show the card columns at the middle of the site, and the background should go white, how can I accomplish that?
I tried to do style a div

```
.testdiv {
  background: #ffffff;
}
```

But that only changes the `div` `background`, which looks like ![this][2]

Edit: My full code for the issue.

```
<section class="bottom-articles">


        <article class="bottom-article">
          <img class="article-image" src="/images/layer-2.jpg">
          <div class="article-text-wrapper">
            <h3 class="article-title">Issue 1</h3>
            <div class="article-description">

            </div>

          </div>
        </article>
```

And for styling, I came up with something like

```
 .bottom-article {
  padding-top: 40px;
  float:right;
  margin-right: 300px;
  padding-right: 80%;

}
```

Comment: add code please

Comment: It would be easier with an image - do you want the cards to have a white background? What shape? Gradient? Padding? etc

Comment: Please add some working snippet or code

Comment: I have added code.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body{background-color:orange;}
#p1 {background-color:transparent;}
#p2 {background-color:#ffffff;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<p>HEX colors:</p>
<p id="p1">transparent</p>
<p id="p2">white</p>
</body>
</html>
```

try doing

```
.testdiv {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```